# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’ on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, cross-platform

***But the same error into browser***

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://abc-test123.com/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’).`

My Browser supports Cors

I have an `extenstion of Cors` for `Chrome` and `CorsE ad-ons for Firefox`

All API's working perfectly from same domain into my localhost server but one of our project API's are not working anymore

We are working on **Slim Framework** here is PHP file Code

```
$corsOptions = array(
    "origin" => "*",
    "exposeHeaders" => array("X-My-Custom-Header", "X-Another-Custom-Header"),
    "maxAge" => 1728000,
    "allowCredentials" => True,
    "allowMethods" => array(" PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"),
    "allowHeaders" => array("X-PINGOTHER")
);
$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim($corsOptions);          
$app->add($cors);
```

I am calling ajax function(which was working before)

```
    var dataString = {
        username: "test",
        password: "test123"
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: varURI, //My url variable
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == "success")
            {
                alert("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Failure");
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried below new things after API error

```
//(1)
$.support.cors = true;

//(2)
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: varURI, //My url variable
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: false, //and true too
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data)
    {}
});
```

## But the same error...

I have checked many questions and applied everything then after asked question here. So need help or any require info which I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

And also look on answer from this link
http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Are you sure if my other api's are working from this domain but for this particular subdomain api's are not working then i need to update .htaccess file ?

Comment: What is the current .htaccess file Header?

Comment: Check your *.conf file in the server such as httpd.conf or apache.conf. What is the 'Header' there ? or any thing specifically mention any URL with Header ? it should be Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: I need to check it, i will update you as soon as possible.

Comment: There is already added this line for cross platform * and actually API working into postman extension

Comment: Check the apache config also.